# How i can call stored procedure (uses zf2, doctrine 2)?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Why it don't work? How i can call stored procedure?

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->objectManager);
$query = $this->objectManager->createNativeQuery('call `ftemplate_setcell`(:t, :col, :row, :p, :r, :v)', $rsm)->
setParameters($this->data);  
$query->Execute();
$this->objectManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 5):

To execute a stored procedure or function you can do it using the connection itself as the following:

```
$conn = $this->getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($storedProcedureSQL);
$stmt->bindParam(':param1', $param1);
$stmt->bindParam(':param2', $param2);
$stmt->execute();
```

and if you have an output parameter you can get it by the following binding:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':outputParam', $outputParam, \PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 32);
```

And after executing the statement you can use the variable `$outputParam` which holds the function or procedure output parameter value.